# Can Capistrano notify me if Unicorn fails to start new processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, unicorn

My Unicorn story: I deploy, the deployment fails (stacks or something else), the response is deployment complete, I have no idea the code served is the correct code unless I look at the logs. Even if look at the logs I have to be watching when Unicorn switches processes.

I start a Unicorn it launches pid=A
pid=A forks to B,C,D,E

A is master

when I signal A with a USR2

it forks itself onces more (F)

NORMALLY

- F re-execs
- F is now a master (but isn't in control of the sockets)
- F forks G,H,I,J (if it can), then signals A to QUIT
- A traps the QUIT, cleans itself up, and hands over the sockets to F
- F runs the new code until we redeploy

BUT... If the code deployed stacks - the application cannot start

- F re-execs,
- F fails, then goes back to A

The deployment failed, and the new code is on the server with the old processes running. This means the site hasn't changed. Capistrano give me the 'all good' sign.

I can see that the deployment fails in the logs
    # app/shared/log/unicorn.rc.log

```
forked child re-executing...
I, [2013-05-24T22:35:16.986618 #88700]  INFO -- : inherited addr=0.0.0.0:51020 fd=10
I, [2013-05-24T22:35:16.987264 #88700]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/u/app/releases/20130524223245/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2: "This  application is deployed correctly" (RuntimeError)
```

I'm trying to get a solution in my deploy script, or my logs, which tells my developers the deploy failed when the Unicorn rolls back to the old process (ie... doesn't start running F) They need to be notified as a command line response so they don't have to open the logs.

Has anyone encountered how to communicate to your team if the new Unicorn process (F) doesn't become the new master for the application?

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly the deploy is failing? What do you mean by "stacks"? Normally, if something fails, Capistrano ought to rollback the deploy before reaching the Unicorn restart task.

Comment: The deploy doesn't fail per se, but the app fails to start on process F, then Unicorn rolls back to process A.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a process monitoring tool such as [God](http://godrb.com/), [Bluepill](https://github.com/arya/bluepill), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) etc. You can then issue USR2 through these tools in your capistrano deploy recipe. These can notify (in several ways) on process failure irrespective of the cause of failure (failed deployment or something else). They can also be configured to attempt restarting a failed process automatically.